# Read JSON string in ExtJS Combobox

Tags: javascript, combobox, extjs

I'm trying to read the following string in an ExtJS combobox:

```
[
   {"id":"1","company_name":"company a"},       
   {"id":"2","company_name":"company b"}
]
```

**EDIT:** I think there is some problem with the way my JSON data source is formatting the string because i dont have any root here. Is it important to have a root element?

Here is my Ext JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function() {

  Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var ds = new Ext.data.Store({
        proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
            url: 'http://somesite.com/someFile.php'
        }),
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({}, 
        [
            {name: 'id', mapping: 'id'},
            {name: 'company_name', mapping: 'company_name'},
        ]
        )
    });


    var search = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        store        : ds,
        fieldLabel   : 'Query string',
        displayField : 'company_name',
        typeAhead    : true,
        loadingText  : 'Searching...',
        pageSize     : 5,
        renderTo     : Ext.getBody(),
        width        : 200,
        mode: 'remote'
    });
```

});

But unfortunately, i'm unable to get this to work. :( Please help!

I'm a n00b at JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need a root.  See the docs for JsonReader, the 'root' config option is **required**.

Also: if you're not doing some cross-domain fetching of data, you probably shouldn't be using ScriptTagProxy.  ScriptTagProxy requires that the server wrap the json-encoded data in a function call.  If you're just calling back your same server, use HttpProxy instead.

Comment: Thanks `timdev`. Now, i'm curious how can i add a root element to my JSON encoded string? i'm using PHP and all i do is take an array from the database and pass it through json_encode(). How would i go about adding a Json root element to it?

Comment: never mind i got the answer to my query here: `http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:Creating_JSON_Data_in_PHP` Thanks `timdev`